# cant write data to model/database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i created `order scaffold` but when i go on `localhost:3000/orders` and type data i want ( name, email, number ) i get **TEMPLATE IS MISSING ERROR** .

This is my controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @orders = Order.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
      @order = Order.new
  end
    def create

  end

     def order_params
       params.require(:order).permit(:name, :number, :email, :pay_type)
     end
end
```

and this is `orders.rb` model :

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :cart 
end
```

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Have you created the corresponding view pages?

Comment: Template is missing means that your views are not available. Do you got the file /views/orders/show.html.erb?

Comment: its created automatically. i have it in app/views/orders/show.html.erb etc....

Comment: What are all the view pages you have?.I believe you might be missing a partial(something like `_form.html.erb`) if you trying to render a partial.Scaffold wont generate partials.

Comment: Please ammend your question with the exact error you're getting.

Comment: this is the error `Missing template orders/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]} Searched in: * "/home/milos/RubyTest/work/last/Bane/projectsignal/app/views" * "/home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-663760e67b80/app/views"` and yes, i have all pages in app/views/orders/

Comment: @Michael Can you post your `new.html.erb`?

Comment: @Pavan this is my new.html.erb `<h1>New order</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', orders_path %>`

Comment: @Michael Do you have `_form.html.erb` in your views folder?.

Comment: @Pavan yes, and this is the content of _form.html.erb : http://pastebin.com/xMxPbPHH  .. my issue is also that with this im trying to write data from form to my orders table in db.

Comment: if u generate order from scaffold ,  than Please check the routes generated and than use it path for localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't implemented your `create` action so the controller drops straight through to render a create view.  However, there is no create view as standard, hence the error `Missing template orders/create...`

The create action is there to create a new record and then redirect to the show or index view.

For example:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)

  @order.save
  redirect_to @order
end
```

Note, this is just an example to get you going; you should be handling any errors from the save and going back to the new action etc.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I can finally write something into db, but after i click submit button, i get this error `undefined local variable or method `set_order' for #<OrdersController:0xb5d8aaa8>` even tho i can see my db populated. / i added this at very top of Order_controller `before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` and if i comment it with # , then everything collapses :O any thoughts?

Comment: That's a new problem; this is just solving the problem of why you got the missing template error.  You should work through your new error and if you can't solve it post a new question giving full details of the error, the orders controller, the view and the Order model.  Hint - when you get a 'undefined method' error, do you have the method in the controller that it's looking for?